# Hibernate: Simulate testConnectionOnCheckout option effect by java code

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using a web application and, sometimes, I have MySql connection problems.
Using the `testConnectionOnCheckout` and `preferredTestQuery` options in the Hibernate configuration file, I resolved the problem and my application is ok now.

But, for better performance, I'd like to obtain the effects of this option only when a particular event occurs in my application. For example:

```
try {
    ...........
}
catch(Exception e) {
    // java code to obtain the same effect as
    // testConnectionOnCheckout option with "Select 1" query
}
```

What Java code do I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to answer such a question is to look it up in the source. So I encourage you to get the source of Hibernate and find the code that tests the connection.

but anyway, here's something simple

```
public static boolean checkConnection(String jdbcUrl, String user, String password){
    boolean result = false;
    try {
                Configuration config = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
                config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", jdbcUrl);
                config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
                config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
                sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
                Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                Assert.assertFalse(sesssion.connection.isReadOnly());
                result = true;
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
                return = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```